# How can I use <keep-alive> in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Video.js in my Nuxt.js project but I don't want the video to start over again from beginning when I change the view of the application. Due to that it would be good to use the  tags on the  tag.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Vue uses a keepAlive flag to cache objects - i am not sure if you can simply expect this to embed into vue logic - but a quick overview on the codebase lets assume that it should be possible to adapt this into vue while keeping the logic - another idea is to make some sort of embedding component

Comment: The only solution is to store current time of your `video` element, and set it again when the view is rendered again.

Answer (score 15):

layout/default.vue

```
<template>
  <nuxt keep-alive/>
</template>
```

References:

- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/with-keep-alive
- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v1.2.0
- https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child/

Comment: Is it good to use it globally? if so `why`?

Answer (score 9):

For those who want to pass props to keep-alive, something like this should do the trick:

```
<template>
    <nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{include: ['name_of_component']}" />
</template>
```

Comment: In my experience only page components works in include array. Also, you have to specify the full path to the page. Something like this works for me:
`<nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{include: ['pages/mypage.vue']}" />`

Comment: What does 'include' actually do here? Does it only include one page or ?

Comment: @lukas23 That is Vue's KeepAlive internal props, so I'd recommend to check [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) for more info